# Enable Action binding using Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to find 'Enable Action binding using Microsoft Bot Framework' option while publishing LUIS application, however it is not there as it is shown in the [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Documentation/blob/master/Content/en-us/LUIS/PublishingToABot.md)

Anybody knows how to unlock this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is available in "Preview" mode.  When logged into your application, click on "Go to Preview" on the top of the page.  When you publish your app, you will see the option to "enable action binding".

- Be sure to enable action fulfillment in one of your intents prior to publishing.
- See below.

[image]

Comment: Problem with this is that BotFramework doesn't support the preview features of Luis (see https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/599, https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/395, https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/222)